# "Duck" Typing vs. Function Arguments in Typescript

Tags: typescript

Typescript performs "duck" typing in certain circumstances, such as when you are checking the validity of an argument to a function against an interface.

For example:

```
interface Named {
  name: string
}

function printName(x: Named) {
  return x.name;
}

const myVar = {
  name: "John",
  happy: "OK", // This extra key-value pair does not break our printName function
};

printName(myVar);
```

However, when you create a variable and define its type, an extra key-value pair *will* throw a type error:

```
const myVar: Named = { name: "Jim", extraVal: "Oops" } // The "extraVal" is not allowed.
```

*1) Why does Typescript check for the *exact* match in the second instance, but not with the parameter passed to the function?*

*2) Are there other instances when duck-typing is used, and how can one tell these instances apart?*

Comment: `{  name: "John",  happy: "OK", }` sure seems like it implements `Named`. The reason it errors in `const x: T` and in nested object literal creation, is pure pragmatism, many errors occur because an _optional_ member was specified under the wrong key.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

TypeScript's type system is [structural](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/typescript-in-5-minutes.html#structural-type-system) (which you're calling "duck" typing), and *in general*, extra properties are not considered to violate the structure of an object type.  In other words, object types in TypeScript are "open/extendible" and not ["closed/exact"](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/12936); the type `{a: string}` is known to have a string-valued `a` property, but is not known to *lack* other properties.

Open object types enable useful things like `interface` and `class` extension, so if `Y extends X` then you can use a `Y` everywhere you could use an `X`, even if `Y` has more functionality.

So to answer your second question, most places in the language rely only on structural subtyping.

---

As far as I know, the only place where the compiler acts as if object types were exact is when you create a new object literal.  The compiler assumes that when you create an object literal that you care about all its properties.  If you then immediately assign such a literal to a type that does not know about all the object literal's properties, the compiler warns you: the compiler will forget about these extra properties and be unable to track them, and it might be a mistake on your part.  This is called [excess property checking](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/interfaces.html#excess-property-checks).  It only kicks in when you have a "fresh" object literal (that has not yet been assigned anywhere) and you assign it to a type that does not expect all its properties.

The example given in the handbook for why this check is desirable involves misspelling optional properties.  If you have a variable of a type like `{ weird?: boolean }` and assign to it the object literal `{ wierd: true }`, the compiler says "hmm, this value *does* fit the type.  It has no `weird` property, which is fine because it's optional.  But it has this extra `wierd` property that I'm going to immediately forget about; why would someone do that?  Maybe that's an error."  I don't know whether you agree with this reasoning or not, but there it is.

---

So to answer your first question, the compiler is happy with

```
const myVar = {
  name: "John",
  happy: "OK"
};    
printName(myVar);
```

because the object literal is not widened in its initial assignment (the type of `myVar` is known to have both a `name` and a `happy` property), and by the time you pass it into `printName()`, it's no longer "fresh".  The compiler will not know about the `happy` property inside the implementation of `printName()`, but it does know about the `happy` property in `myVar`.

And it's unhappy with

```
const myVar: Named = { name: "Jim", happy: "OK" };
```

because it gets caught by excess property checking.  The type of `myVar` will not contain any reference to `happy`.

---

Okay, hope that helps; good luck!

Comment: TLDR, "As far as I know, the only place where the compiler acts as if object types were exact is when you create a new object literal... This is called excess property checking. It only kicks in when you have a "fresh" object literal (that has not yet been assigned anywhere) and you assign it to a type that does not expect all its properties." This whole post is great, thank you!!

Answer (score 1):

In addition to @jcalz's amazing answer, there are two typescriptical ways to bypass the check:

```js
const myVar: Named & any = { name: "Jim", extraVal: "Oops" };

const myVar: Named = { name: "Jim", extraVal: "Oops" } as Named;
```

Comment: What's the name of the & syntax?

Comment: @HarryCramer intersection. Specifically, `T & U` computes a type that is said to be the intersection of `T` and `U`.

Comment: Note that the intersection `Named & any` is equivalent to `any` and the compiler forgets all about `Named`.  That is, there's no difference between `const myVar: Named & any` and `const myVar: any`... leading to weirdness like [this](https://tsplay.dev/AwQ67N); so I wouldn't recommend `& any` unless you intend to turn off type checking entirely.  The type assertion (`as Named`) is better, but since type assertions allow you to *narrow* as well as *widen* a type, you end up with potential unsafe operations as in [this](https://tsplay.dev/oN58Zw), so be careful.